# Symfony3, how to load an external choice list in a form?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I don't know if I'm facing a bug or doing something wrong. I'm trying to load choices for a ChoiceType form from a custom class, but I get the following error:

`Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\LazyChoiceList::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\Loader\ChoiceLoaderInterface, none given`

My custom class:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form\ChoiceLists;

use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\SimpleChoiceList;
use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\LazyChoiceList;

class DepartmentsChoiceList extends LazyChoiceList
{
    public function loadChoiceList()
    {
         $choices = array(
             '01' => "Ain",
             '02' => "Aisne",
             '03' => "Allier",
             '04' => "Alpes de Haute Provence",
             '05' => "Alpes (Hautes)",
             //....
             '94' => "Val de Marne",
             '95' => "Val d&acute;Oise",
             '98' => "Mayotte",
             '9A' => "Guadeloupe",
             '9B' => "Guyane",
             '9C' => "Martinique",
             '9D' => "R&eacute;union",
             );
         return new SimpleChoiceList($choices);
    }
}
```

And in my formType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('birthDepartment', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Département :',
            'required' => false,
            'choices' => new DepartmentsChoiceList(),
         )
     );
```

I found very few documentation for this feature.

Comment: Never used this class myself by I do know that S3 swapped the keys and values in the array.  Look at the example in the docs carefully.

Comment: You should always extend AbstractType and return the parent type in getParent() method

Comment: @mblaettermann - ChoiceList is not a form type.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're right

Comment: You should implements this interface in your custom class : http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/Factory/ChoiceListFactoryInterface.html

Comment: @Wissem Thanks for the tip. I solved my problem implementing a class with a public static array, and didn't try to do it the "symfony way", since I could'nt find any working example.

Comment: You could use choice_loader and a ChoiceLoaderInterface implementation, which also helps if your list gets larger. Full example here:  http://www.strehle.de/tim/weblog/archives/2016/02/24/1588

Answer (score 0):

Here is my procedure on Symfony 5.4. It may not be the best way to do it, but it's the only one I found that works.

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Controller\ApiController;

use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\Loader\ChoiceLoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\ArrayChoiceList;

class DepartmentChoiceList implements ChoiceLoaderInterface
{

    public function loadChoiceList($value = null)
    {
        $choices = array(
            '01' => "Ain",
            '02' => "Aisne",
            '03' => "Allier",
            '04' => "Alpes de Haute Provence",
            '05' => "Alpes (Hautes)",
            //....
            '94' => "Val de Marne",
            '95' => "Val d&acute;Oise",
            '98' => "Mayotte",
            '9A' => "Guadeloupe",
            '9B' => "Guyane",
            '9C' => "Martinique",
            '9D' => "R&eacute;union",
        );
        return new ArrayChoiceList($choices);
    }


    public function loadChoicesForValues(array $values, $value = null)
    {
        $result = [];

        return $result;
    }

    public function loadValuesForChoices(array $choices, $value = null)
    {
        $result = [];

        return $result;
    }
}
```

And formType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('department', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => 'Department',
                'choice_loader' => new DepartmentChoiceList(),
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }
```